# How to apply validation for password and verify password

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have created a directive for validation, which make sure that same data is entered in password and verify password fields, Its working fine If I type something in it, If I type the password and then remove it, it does not work.
Check the plunker here
http://plnkr.co/edit/tsNqEpMtLY1aEkxBjNcw?p=preview

```
Type something in password field -> Update btn will disabled
Clear the password field by pressing backspace -> Update btn still disabled
```

here is the js code

```
.directive('equalsTo', function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                var sc = scope;
                scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
                    var eqCtrl = scope.$eval(attrs.equalsTo);
                    if (ctrl.$viewValue===eqCtrl.$viewValue) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('equalsTo', true);
                        eqCtrl.$setValidity('equalsTo', true);
                    } else {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('equalsTo', false);
                        eqCtrl.$setValidity('equalsTo', false);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: The same is working for me

Comment: Type abc in password field, without doing anything just press backspace to remove all these characters you just type so that password field is empty. You will see it will still show error

Comment: i dont see any wrong behaviour there. works predictable

Comment: @Flextra If you did't get the wrong behavior then you have not understand my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After deleting password you compare empty string with undefined value:

```
ctrl.$viewValue===eqCtrl.$viewValue
```

You should check if both variables are empty or undefined then form is valid:

```
if (ctrl.$viewValue===eqCtrl.$viewValue || (!!!ctrl.$viewValue && !!!eqCtrl.$viewValue)) {
  ctrl.$setValidity('equalsTo', true);
  eqCtrl.$setValidity('equalsTo', true);
} else { 
  ctrl.$setValidity('equalsTo', false);
  eqCtrl.$setValidity('equalsTo', false);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/QKOr2K7NXjOMGtnKdeWT?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
.directive('equals', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
            require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
                if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

                // watch own value and re-validate on change
                scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {
                    validate();
                });

                // observe the other value and re-validate on change
                attrs.$observe('equals', function (val) {
                    validate();
                });

                var validate = function () {
                    // values
                    var val1 = ngModel.$viewValue;
                    var val2 = attrs.equals;

                    // set validity
                    ngModel.$setValidity('equals', val1 === val2);
                };
            }
        }
    })
```

Try this directive.